# 404 returned in CORS request for some web api calls from angular service

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-web-api, cors

I have an angular application that retrieves data from an ASP.Net web api service.

The web api is hosted on a different domain.

The web api contains multiple URL's to query different types of data, for instance `site2/api/Employees`, `site2/api/Managers`, etc.

The web api has a global configuration, as it does normally, i.e. no special configurations are made for any specific controllers.

I have created different controllers in angularjs and for each controller there is a service(copy-pasted code, but I have checked and updated all the necessary references correctly).

When I access `site2/api/Employees` from my angular code in site1, data is returned from the web api service.

However, when I access `/site2/api/Managers`  from my angular code I get an error OPTIONS:`/site2/api/Managers` 404 not found
XMLHttpRequest cannot load `/site2/api/Managers` invalid status code 404

Could someone please,provide a solution for this issue

Comment: Sounds like your issue is on the back-end side of things. What happens when you do the same request via Postman (or Poster if you're on Firefox) ?

Answer (score 0):

is i am not angularjs user but i can help you in cors

The cors request works when browsers allow cross-domain request.

One way is to Allow Cors request is through client browser

- ([jquery](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.support/)) jQuery.support.cors = true this line would be help full if
  you are aiming IE Only
- For Enabling in other Browser you may check [this](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/cors/) javscript

Another way is to set HTTP responses header to all access to Cors from server side

below is my php code to all access to Cors through HTTP responses header

```
<?php

header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin:  http://yourdomain.com');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST, GET, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type');
```

i hope this may help you..